# HTML Agility - Finding the right node

Tags: c#, xpath, windows-phone-8, html-agility-pack

I know there are a lot of HTML Agility questions, but I could not find a solution for my problem.

I have the following snippet from a loaded HTML page:

```
<div id="packageInfo" >
<div id="package_text" class="texts">Packages
    <span id="numberOfPackages">1</span>
</div>
<div class="texts" style="width: 200px;"> <-- THIS IS THE NODE I WANT TO FETCH
    Productnumber: 21036
    <br />
    Width:29cm
    <br />
    Height:13cm
    <br />
    Length:212cm
    <br />
    Weight:37,5kg
    <br />
    Number: 1<br />
</div>  
</div>
```

Please notice the line:

```
<div class="texts" style="width: 200px;"> <-- THIS IS THE NODE I WANT TO FETCH
```

I have tried

```
HtmlNode temp = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@id='package_text']");
string test = temp.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='texts']").InnerText.Trim();
```

but this returns null.

The following however works (but does not give me what I need):

```
HtmlNode temp = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@id='package_text']");
string test = temp.SelectSingleNode("//span[@id='numberOfPackages']").InnerText.Trim();
```

I admit that I do not understand the XPATH correctly

I have several entries in the HTML for:

```
<div class="texts">
```

so it is important that I select the correct one.

I have also searched around for a solution using StreamPosition og LineNumber, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

`<div class="texts">` is not inside `<div id="package_text">`, it is next to `<div id="package_text">` instead.

You can try this XPath :

```
.//div[@id='package_text']/following-sibling::div[@class='texts']
```

Comment: +1 Didn't know that `following-sibling` is supported by HtmlAgilityPack

Answer (score 0):

With the HTML code you provided, `<div class="texts">` is the second child of `<div id="packageInfo" >`

So something like this (untested) might work:

`//div[@id='packageInfo']/div[2]`